# Cheapest flight generally from Ulan Bator to a country an Australian citizen doesnt need a full page visa for?

Tags: air-travel, budget, australian-citizens, mongolia, ulan-bator

My current goal on this trip is to get to Ulan Bator, Mongolia but the Mongolian visa will use up the last blank page of my passport and I intend to keep travelling for a couple months more.

So yes I know I might be able to obtain a new passport at the Australian embassy in UB but I don't mind the restriction and am considering my options.

I'm interested in everywhere, the only restrictions are the generally cheapest flight, and the destination has to be a place where Australians don't need a visa, or where the visa-on-arrival does not take up a full page. (USA is also out as I happen to require a visa there.)

I know flight prices change and there are changing special offers etc so I'm not looking for the absolute cheapest, just the destination which should pretty much always be available and pretty much always be cheap. If the cheapest is still not super cheap it's still an acceptable answer.

Experience will probably provide the best answer since if none of us are familiar with flight prices out of Mongolia we'll be able to find current cheap flights on the flight search engines, but it will be harder to know for sure which of those destinations are usually the cheap ones and which are seasonal or special prices.

<sup>(For example there might be cheaper flights sometimes but generally the cheapest places to fly from Sydney are Kuala Lumpur and Singapore.)</sup>

Comment: Shopping is when you ask for product recommendations - read the offical Stack Exchange stance: **[Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)**. Broad is when there are many answers. Are you saying you found more than ten and they're all the cheapest? Should we close all the questions about

Comment: If we assume that longer flights have higher costs, your destinations are limited to Bangkok, Tokyo, and Seoul.

Comment: @Karlson: Those are all good. But I also found flights to Hong Kong and Taiwan. I was surprised to find a couple to the US even - but I can't use those.

Comment: Have you considered flightfox? You can start a contest with criteria like this...

Comment: @hippietrail is cheapest only relevent for the flight or would dirt cheap destinations compensate a higher ticket fee?

Comment: @MarkMayo: FlightFox would give me the cheapest specific flight at a specific time so I could use that if I do end up needing an exit strategy from UB. But I thought it would be good to know which places will "always be cheapest" to fly to.

Comment: @Frietjeoorlog: Possibly. I was thinking of tickets for "a few hundred dollars or less" but didn't want to put that in the question in case it turned out the cheapest ones that fit my criteria were more like $900. But it seems that Thailand is likely to be a contender either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cheapest I could find was Manila, Philippines. Prices start from $360 `USD`, I checked the price for two months from now and the prices ranges are the same. Also, few airlines offer similar prices.

Regarding the VOA, AFAIK the VOA for the Philippines is a normal sized stamp.